# ODM: Cannot achieve bi-directional relationship

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have two documents. I am trying to find all papers that are associated to a specific person. The documents are saving in their collections, and a reference is being created from `Person` to `Paper`, but not the other way around.

```php
/** @ODM\Document */
class Paper
{
/**
 * @ODM\Id
 */
protected $id;

/** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Person", cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="papers") */
protected $person;


public function __get($property) {
    return $this->$property;
}

public function __set($property, $value) {
    $this->$property = $value;
}


public function toArray() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
}
```

```php
/** @ODM\Document */
class Person
{
/**
 * @ODM\Id
 */
protected $id;

/** @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Paper", cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="person") */
protected $papers;


public function __get($property) {
    return $this->$property;
}

public function __set($property, $value) {
    $this->$property = $value;
}


public function toArray() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
}
```

**CREATE A NEW BI-DIRECTIONAL REFERENCE**

```php
$person = $dm->getRespository('Person')->find($person_id);

$paper = new Paper();
$person->papers->add($paper);

$dm->persist($person);
$dm->flush();
```

Later in the code, this query returns 0 results; shouldn't it be returning papers written by specified person?

```php
$papers = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Paper')
    ->field('person.$id')->equals(new \MongoId($person_id_as_string))
    ->getQuery()->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Paper::person is annotated with "mappedBy" it means that Paper is not the "owning side" and doctrine will not persist any changes to Paper::person.

To make your query work, make Paper the owning side so Paper stores the reference to Person.

```
/** @ODM\Document */
class Person
{
    /** @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Paper", mappedBy="person") */
    protected $papers;
}

/** @ODM\Document */
class Paper
{    
    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Person", inversedBy="papers") */
    protected $person;
}
```

Creating a paper and persisting a reference to person:

```
$person = $dm->getRespository('Person')->find($person_id);

$paper = new Paper();
$paper->person = $person;

$dm->persist($paper);
$dm->flush();
```

Querying Papers by $person:

```
$papers = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Paper')
    ->field('person')->references($person)
    ->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: What if i would like to query the "Paper" side in the original code example do i have access to the reference to Person?

Comment: Could you rephrase this? I'm not sure what you mean.